# JavaScript variable setting issue

Tags: javascript, variables

How can I set this class 'output' value into a variable on a button click in JavaScript

```html
<input class="output" type="hidden" name="output" value="[{"lx":25,"ly":43,"mx":25,"my":42},{"lx":25,"ly":41,"mx":25,"my":43},{"lx":108,"ly":34,"mx":108,"my":33}]">
```

**Expected output:**

```
var myVal = [{lx:25,ly:43,mx:25,my:42},{lx:25,ly:41,mx:25,my:43},{lx:108,ly:34,mx:108,my:33}];
```

Comment: use my myVal  in attrtibue value

Comment: how? would you please give through example.

Comment: You're using double quotes inside a double-quote delimited attribute, it's deemed to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/831/

HTML:

```
<input class="output" type="hidden" name="output" value='[{" lx ":25,"ly ":43,"mx ":25,"my ":42},{"lx ":25,"ly ":41,"mx ":25,"my ":43},{"lx ":108,"ly ":34,"mx ":108,"my ":33}]' />
<button>Get</button>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").on("click", function () {
        var v = $("input").val()
        console.log(JSON.parse(v));
    });
});
```

**Note:** Make sure you use single quote in the value attribute of input. See the HTML in this answer here. Otherwise this will not work.

**This answer is in jquery. However, same can be done in javascript too. The point is to correct the HTML and then parse the input value**

Comment: var v = $("input").val(). This is will be "output". My problem is solved. marking your answer as 'ANSWER'.

Comment: @sharmoon You'll have problems in parsing that value. It .val() will return a string. But you need it as on object or json. You may need JSON.parse()

Answer (score 1):

First fix the quoting on your HTML so you use a single quote to start and end the string and then double quotes inside of it (what you have now is not legal HTML):

```
<input class="output" type="hidden" name="output" value='[{"lx":25,"ly":43,"mx":25,"my":42},{"lx":25,"ly":41,"mx":25,"my":43},{"lx":108,"ly":34,"mx":108,"my":33}]'>
```

Assuming you can use the HTML hierarchy to get a reference to that `<input>` tag into a variable named `elem` and you fix the string delimiters on your `value="xxx"` string, then you can do this:

```
var myVal = JSON.parse(elem.value);
```

If you need help getting the DOM reference for the `<input>` tag, you could do something like this:

```
var elem = document.querySelectorAll(".output")[0];
var myVal = JSON.parse(elem.value);
```

This assumes that the target `<input>` tag is the first element in the page with `class="output"`.  If that's not the case, then you will have to post the HTML for the page so we can advise how to select the desired `<input>` tag from the page DOM.

---

If, you had a button in your HTML:

```
<button id="getdata">Get Data</button>
```

And, you wanted to hook a click handler up to that, you could put this Javascript in a script tag at the end of your document:

```
document.getElementById("getdata").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var elem = document.querySelectorAll(".output")[0];
    var myVal = JSON.parse(elem.value); 
    // do something with myVar here
});
```

---

Putting it all together into a working snippet:

```js
document.getElementById("getdata").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var elem = document.querySelectorAll(".output")[0];
    var myVal = JSON.parse(elem.value); 
    // do something with myVar here
    log(JSON.stringify(myVal));
});

function log(d) {
    var item = document.createElement("div");
    item.textContent = d;
    document.body.appendChild(item);
}
```

```html
<input class="output" type="hidden" name="output" value='[{"lx":25,"ly":43,"mx":25,"my":42},{"lx":25,"ly":41,"mx":25,"my":43},{"lx":108,"ly":34,"mx":108,"my":33}]'><br>
<button id="getdata">Get Data (press me)</button><br><br>
```

Comment: @sharmoon - I'm not sure what that last comment means.  I have a full working snippet in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

With plain js:

```js
var myVal = null;
var set = function() {
  myVal = document.getElementsByName("output")[0].value;
  alert(myVal); // string type
  myVal = JSON.parse(myVal);
  alert(myVal); // json type
};
```

```html
<!-- updated quotes for value attribute -->
<input class="output" type="hidden" name="output" value='[{"lx":25,"ly":43,"mx":25,"my":42},{"lx":25,"ly":41,"mx":25,"my":43},{"lx":108,"ly":34,"mx":108,"my":33}]' />
<input type="button" onclick="set()" value="Set" />
```